Deep-translator compatibility in Python code when creating APK with Buildozer
I am creating an Android application.
I am making a Python 3.11 code using deep-translator library.
Then i use Buildozer to make the APK.
Finally i test the APK application with a real mobile Samsung Galaxy A71 with Android 13 installed.
The problem:
When i launch the application in Android, the application crash immediately. I don't know why. I don't know how to see the logs in Android.
Here is a simple main.py Python code to show the problem:
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.app import App

from deep_translator import GoogleTranslator

kivy.require('2.3.0')

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()

If i remove the following line it works, so the problem is this line:
from deep_translator import GoogleTranslator

Here is the content of my buildozer.spec:
title = Excel File Translator
package.name = excelfiletranslator
package.domain = com.astrobalyka.excelfiletranslator
source.dir = .
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas
version = 0.1
requirements = python3,kivy==2.3.0,deep-translator
orientation = portrait
osx.python_version = 3
osx.kivy_version = 2.3.0
fullscreen = 0
android.permissions = android.permission.INTERNET,android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE

Questions:

Can i use this library or it will never work?
Must i use another library?
Why deep-translate do not work?



Android has a logcat where errors are sent: Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this? 2) deep-translate library author already made an Android app, as it is open-source you should review it: https://deep-translator.readthedocs.io/en/latest/README.html#the-translator-mobile-app

